Test files from Xcode project not considered as test files in SonarCloud
I have created a very simple test project to try to implement SonarCloud in the Github Actions of my Swift project.
The project root contains a TestCIModel folder containing the sources, and a TestCIModelTests folder containing the tests.
Model.swift inside the sources folder:
public struct Character {
    
    public var name: String
    public var age: Int
    
    public init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    
    public mutating func update(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

TestCIModelTests.swift inside the tests folder:
import XCTest
@testable import TestCIModel

final class TestCIModelTests: XCTestCase {
    
    var character: Character?
    
    func testCharacterInitialization() {
        let testName = "john"
        let testAge = 10
        
        character = .init(
            name: testName,
            age: testAge
        )
        
        XCTAssertNotNil(character)
        XCTAssertEqual(character?.name, testName)
        XCTAssertEqual(character?.age, testAge)        
    }
    
}

I've also set a sonar-project.properties file at the root of my project:
sonar.organization={organization}
sonar.projectKey={project_key}

sonar.sources=TestCIModel

sonar.tests=TestCIModelTests

And I've added a Github action to start a SonarCloud analysis on each pull request:
on:
  pull_request:

name: Pull Request

jobs:
  sonarcloud:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: SonarCloud Scan
      uses: sonarsource/sonarcloud-github-action@v2.3.0
      env:
        SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}

Everything seems to run fine... but in SonarCloud's analysis, it looks like the test file is treated like a source file:

Resulting in a 0% code coverage result:

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help!
